# GenericRegex for taking outer part of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string, The string looks like :

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator
```

I want to get the content from the third "/" from the left to the second last from the right or say i want to make it more generic.

Please provide any possible solution.

this is the output i need `wiki/Uniform_resource_locator`

Comment: tell the actual output... I can't count it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex you require is this :

```
(?:.*?\/){3}(.*?)(.*)(?:\/.*?){2}$
```

a generic regex:

```
(?:.*?\/){n}(.*?)(.*)(?:\/.*?){m}$
```

substitute 3 and 2 with n and m and you will get your result

demo here:

http://regex101.com/r/cN7vR5

this will get you the result as : `wiki/Uniform_resource_locator`
which is from the third to the second last `/`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do :

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator')
uri.path[/(\w+\/\w+)/, 1]
# => "wiki/Uniform_resource_locator"
```

Check this : [`Basic example`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#module-URI-label-Basic+example)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator'

p s.split('/').last(2).join('/') #=> "wiki/Uniform_resource_locator"
```